# Floodfilling a texture in HLSL Compute shader

Tags: hlsl, compute-shader

I have a very large texture which I want to fill with values representing "distance in units from a river tile".
The texture is already seeded with these origin river points (meaning distance/value = 0 in them).

From these points I want to floodfill outwards, incrementing the value with each step from these origin points.

Doing this on the CPU is no problem using a stack or similiar structure but ideally I want to do this in the middle of a Compute shader execution which runs over the entire texture.

I have read [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/149964/shader-floodfill-alogrithm) which sound similiar to what I want to do but it mentions there might be a smarter way to do this with Compute shaders - which is what I am using.

Any ideas on how to solve this on compute shaders?

Comment: You may be interested in [the Jump Flooding algorithm](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jump+flooding+algorithm&ia=software), which is specifically designed to speed up distance field computation on GPUs. it's an approximation, but in practice the errors are usually negligible, and it's *fast* compared to exact algorithms. [Here's the paper that kicked off its use in this way](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~tants/jfa/i3d06.pdf)

Comment: Yepp - I implemented it and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! Want to document your solution in an Answer below to help other devs in the future?